# Flask App outputting Excel file

Tags: python, flask, openpyxl

Here's what I currently have... My application is outputting an excel file, I just don't know how to output an excel file that has MY DATA in it. Right now it's just outputting an excel file that just contains "test" in Cell A1, and I know that's because of my line that says `strIO.write('test')`. How can  I make sure that the file that outputs as a download to the user contains all of the information from the file that I processed?

Thanks.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, send_file
import StringIO


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """<title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="/uploader" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>"""

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(f.filename)
        return process(f.filename)

def process(filename):

    routename = ['ZYAA', 'ZYBB', 'ZYCC']
    supervisors = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    workbook = load_workbook(filename)
    worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('A', 'B', hidden=True)
    routes = worksheet.columns[2]
    i = 2
    worksheet['D1'] = 'Supervisor'
    for route in routes:
        if route.value in routename:
            pos = routes.index(route)
            worksheet['D' + str(i)].value = supervisors[pos]
            i += 1

    workbook.save(filename)
    filename = filename.strip(".xlsx")
    filename = filename + ".xls"

    strIO = StringIO.StringIO()
    strIO.write('test')
    strIO.seek(0)
    return send_file(strIO,
                     attachment_filename=filename,
                     as_attachment=True)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: You should send the file you created instead of the test string.

Comment: Hmm. What would that look like? return send_file(filename, attachment_filename=filename, as_attachment=True)?

Comment: Yes. (if that doesn't work add the exception you are getting)

Comment: NEVERMIND had a typo

Comment: If you'd like to post what you said as an answer I will accept it! Thank you so much!

Comment: This isn't a forum. Don't need to edit the title to solved

Comment: FWIW openpyxl also provides the `save_virtual_workbook` function so that you can write this straight to the response.  http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.writer.excel.html?highlight=save_virtual_workbook

Comment: Would that be better than using send_file?

Comment: You still need send_file, but you don't need to actually write a file, but everything will happen in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `send_file` function in flask sends the file you are specifying in the first argument (compare to the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.send_file)). You put there `strIO` which means that the string you saved there will get send. If you want to send the file you are prepering before, you should put that file there, i.e.

```
send_file(filename, attachment_filename=filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this. Could you take a look at this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464974/flask-app-only-only-works-1-time-for-file-output